# No Such Module error in objective-c framework inside Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I implement a API to my project. However, class doesn't see the library inside a swift class. (I was using the same api with same project before but now I created a new project but now It isn't working). 
First I implement the class in build Phase then create "New copy file phase" but didn't work. I also create bridging header file.

[image: First]

[image][image: 3[![][3]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jJyF.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I delete framework from build settings etc.. then moved it to the project directory and It worked!